# Cant change span text in ajaxStart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jquery 2.2.3

I have an ajaxstart method and i want to update the text of a span before showing my modal:

```
       $(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () {
        $('#spnModalProgress').html("I should change");
        $('#spnModalProgress').show();
    },
    ajaxStop: function() {
      $('#spnModalProgress').hide();
    }
});
```

This is the html:

```
  <div class="modal">
  </div>
<span id="spnModalProgress" class="centerModaltext">Get rid of this text</span>
```

When i make an ajax call, the code is firing, but the span text is not changing at all. My modal window will appear, but i took that code out to prove its not interfering with the span. As a matter of fact, i cannot manipulate the span at all. It will not show when I'm telling it to show. How do I get the text to change in ajaxStart? If i can get past this, i'm sure the other things i want to do will fall into place. Thanks

Comment: You have not closed the string : html("I should change);

Comment: Thats just a typo...the browser would have caught that..i've updated the question

Comment: jose's answer below gives an indication that it's working because there is a setTimeout happening to fire that modalProgress span...is it firing immediately on load and you just don't see it actually happening?

Answer (score 2):

I've copied your code and make ajax call and it's working for me.

```js
       $(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () {
        $('#spnModalProgress').html("I should change");
        $('#spnModalProgress').show();
    },
    ajaxStop: function() {
      setTimeout(function(){$('#spnModalProgress').hide()}, 2000);
    }
});

$.get('url');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
</div>
<span id="spnModalProgress" class="centerModaltext">Get rid of this text</span>
```

Comment: Ok, then i have other problems. Thanks